# Who first defined/coined The Double-Spending Problem?

Tags: doublespend

The Double-Spending problem is a variant of the Byzantine Generals Problem which has a nice write up by Lamport, Shostak and Pease. But who first coined/defined the specific Double-Spending problem? Or linked the BGP to the digital currency domain? Does there exist a proper academic write up, defining the problem, that predates bitcoin?

I searched for a bit and can only find write ups after Nakamoto's publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Does there exist a proper academic write up, defining the problem, that predates bitcoin?**

Google ngrams shows the phrase being used as early as the 1970s but that is probably not in the context of digital currencies.

The earliest reference I could easily find is in several articles in "Advances in Cryptology - CRYPTO '93"

For example in "Untraceable Off-Line Cash in Wallet with Observers" by Stefan Brands.

Since several articles mention double spending I expect the coinage of this phrase in this context is older than 1993.

However there were no mentions in CRYPTO '92.